# Is this a possible interpretation of quantum tunneling?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-tunneling

Suppose we have a particle in a finite potential well where the potential is $V_0$ and the ensemble average momentum is $\langle p\rangle$, so that the average kinetic energy $$\langle T\rangle =\frac{\langle p
\rangle^2}{2m}$$ (or should it be $\langle T\rangle =\frac{\langle p
^2\rangle}{2m}$ ?) is less than $V_0$ . But because this is an ensemble average, there are possible momentums(say $p^*$) which are greater than $\langle p\rangle$ and the corresponding possible kinetic energies are such that $$\frac{p^*{^2}}{2m}>V_0$$
So that there is some possibility that the particle may pass through the barrier, and this possibility decreases as $V_0$ gets bigger and bigger.

Is this reasoning correct? If not, why not?

Comment: What about  a Dirac Delta potential?

Comment: I haven't studied that yet, but I'm guessing that it's a dirac delta potential that allows tunneling?

Comment: @Triatticus I've been looking at some of the answers related to tunneling, and I don't get how the energy-time uncertainty explains tunneling through Dirac Delta potential too.

Comment: Yes there is transmission through a Delta potential, you don't need the uncertainty relation to show that.

Comment: I know, it follows from the Schroedinger equation and the continuity conditions just like the finite potential case. It's just that everywhere I looked about how one should interpret tunneling, people just kept on bringing the energy-time uncertainty.

Comment: What kind of interpretation are you looking for? It sounds like you're trying to give a purely quantum phenomenon a classical interpretation.

Comment: It's a nice idea to think of a quantum system as a random combination of classical systems. It's been tried, and it turns out that it doesn't work -- you can only get the right answers if you allow some of the classical states to have _negative_ probability.

Comment: And of course in retrospect this is obvious, because quantum mechanics is different from classical mechanics. If it really were just a slightly hidden variant of classical mechanics, we wouldn't have had to come up with it in the first place. In reality, quantum mechanics is so very different from classical, and we do need that difference to describe the world.

Answer (score 1):

Tunneling is a quantum mechanical phenomenon, whereas you are treating it as a classical statistical ensemple, mixing potentials too.

A quantum mechanical solution exists for a *single*  particle in a given potential, which solution comes from solving the relevant quantum mechanical equation. It is called $Ψ$, and  $Ψ^*Ψ$ gives the probability of the particle to be at (x,y,z,t) If the potential well is not an infinite potential well there will be a probability for the particle to be outside it, i.e the wavefunction to have a value outside it.

An example of tunneling through a barrier is shown [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/barr.html) :

[image: tunneling]

> According to classical physics, a particle of energy E less than the height U0 of a barrier could not penetrate - the region inside the barrier is classically forbidden. But the wavefunction associated with a free particle must be continuous at the barrier and will show an exponential decay inside the barrier. The wavefunction must also be continuous on the far side of the barrier, so there is a finite probability that the particle will tunnel through the barrier.

Please read the link.

Comment: Anna, as far as I can tell Uo is also an average value in practice. So, a classical explanation could be possible.

Comment: No, classical will not do. Classical is about measurement of energy etc. Quantum mechanical is about probabilities. There is no probability classically that a barrier can be passed as in the above quantum mechanical analysis.

Comment: Anna, in this paper: Tunneling and the Vacuum Zero-Point Radiation, Braz. J. Phys. vol.37 no.1a São Paulo Mar. 2007 it is argued that "the classical particle can escape from the potential well due to the action of the zero-point fluctuating fields". The zero-point fields are, according to the theory of stochastic electrodynamics, the reason behind the Casimir force.

Comment: Stochastic electrodynamics is not main stream physics, it works on the hypothesis that the quantum frame emerges from a deterministic frame. This site works with the main stream hypothesis of physics, that the underlying nature of matter cannot be deterministic. read the first sentence  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_electrodynamics#targetText=Stochastic%20electrodynamics%20is%20a%20term,Lorentz%20invariant%20random%20electromagnetic%20radiation.&targetText=Others%20have%20made%20contributions%2C%20alterations,SED%20to%20problems%20in%20QED.

Comment: The Wiki page is nonsense. Stochastic electrodynamics has nothing to do with Bohm's theory. It is in fact classical electromagnetism (which is as mainstream as you can get) with some assumption about the initial state (zero-point field is a real EM field). I also disagree that the assumption of indeterminism is mainstream. Two Nobel laureates in the relevant field ('t Hooft and Weinberg) lean towards determinism (superdeterminism for 'T Hooft, many worlds for Weinberg). But anyway, my point is that it is possible to get "tunneling" classically.